# How to track Continuous Job execution per Thing in AWS-IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-jobs

I use AWS IoT to manage Things.
I have a Dynamic Thing Group with Continuous IoT Job attached, so every Thing eventually (based on conditions) can be added to this Group and a thing will be notified on a Job to be executed. This one works perfect.

Now I need to track Job `SUCCEEDED` event for every Thing (Job execution). How can I do this using AWS IoT services?

I was trying to do this using AWS IoT Rules with the following SQL expression:

`SELECT * FROM '$aws/events/jobExecution/my-continuous-job-id/succeeded'`

but without success, no events were observed. However, at the same time I can see that Job was successfully executed as in Thing as in the AWS IoT Web Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found the answer. So to handle job execution events one should activate this feature in AWS IoT Core explicitly which is not obvious from the first glance:

- AWS Web Console:

AWS IoT -> Settings -> Manage Events -> Check "Job execution: success, failed, rejected, canceled, removed"

- AWS CLI:

  ```
  aws iot update-event-configurations --event-configurations "{\"JOB_EXECUTION\":{\"Enabled\": true}}"
  ```

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-events.html